Git submodules, versioning and forks configuration
I have the following situation and I need some guidelines on how to use git as optimal as possible. I have a web application developed in laravel. It will be used by multiple clients as standalone installations. This application has a core with different versions (releases) and a bunch of modules (not laravel modules, my own modules of features inside the application) each with their own versions.
When installing it to a client I select which modules will be used (in a config file) and create a build and install it. Apart from that each client will need customizations. I developed the application in such a way that all customizations will be inside a separate folder (something like hooks) and completely independent of the core and modules, so that i can override the core or main modules without affecting the customizations.
How can I mantain via git the core, the modules, versions of core and modules, client’s instalations (core and modules) and client’s customizations somehow independently but in the same time linked so that when i create a new version of the core or for a module I can push it to all client’s git/installations (not automatic)? How can I keep track of versions per core and per modules so I can compare and know what version is each client running on?
So far I managed to use git submodules for the modules and link them to the core repository. I would also like to have dev brand and main brand + versioning for both the core and modules.
But when I create a new installation to the client how can I fork the core and only some of the modules, and a new module (customization) and some how keep the core and the selected modules linked to the main core and modules?
